# Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/ContentCodingType$1

Tags: rest, android-annotations, spring-android

I test androidannotations framework, but have some error when I add spring-android libs.
I create repo for my test project [open_git_repo](https://bitbucket.org/mbykov/aat/src/) !

### At this moment,  I have in gradle console

---

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":       {},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex    files define Lorg/springframework/http/ContentCodingType$1;","position{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/ContentCodingType$1;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)","position":{},"original":"\tat        com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)"} 
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/ContentCodingType$1;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/ContentCodingType$1;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

---

### My build gradle script

---

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mbykov.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3'
dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3"
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}
sourceSets {}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
 compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-   template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
maven {
    url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
}}
```

---

I don't understand this error, could somebody explain what is going on?

Comment: `com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/ContentCodingType$1`
This type of error often comes from the fact that the support library is included several times.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Support Library. The Spring Android RestTemplate library is included multiple times (as the error message says).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First, the declared dependencies:

```
//compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
 compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-   template:1.0.1.RELEASE
```

I know you commented out the first dependency, but make sure you do not have two at the some time. This will cause duplicate classes in your classpath and dex fails.

Secondly, you have the spring android rest template jar in your *libs* folder. This will also cause duplicate, since you are referring to this library as a dependency from repository, and also as a dependency from your local *libs* folder. Just delete the *libs* folder, it is totally unnecessary. You should always use proper dependency management, e.g. just declare them in your buildscript and let gradle download them with transitive dependencies, correct version and dependency conflict resolution etc. Remove this line, too:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it's working for you. ;)